# Jsoup - getting class element with whitespace in name

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to grab the value of this class by tag "c2 l n".

```
<td class="c2 l n"><span class"generic">0,63</span></td>
```

In Jsoup i have tried this :

```
String value="c2 l n";
Elements Stock_Data_Change = doc.getElementsByClass(value);
```

But it keeps coming up empty..
it works fine with other classnames such as "ju.l", it seems to miss the whitespaces.
Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Class names don't have spaces in them, elements have multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks :) Got it with doc.select("td.c2.l.n");

Comment: If its solved, please post your solution as an answer and accept it (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Interesting reading in that blog, didnt think of it like that before..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As Dave Newton answered in comments above, we are talking about elements,that has multiple classes in them.
To get the value of this element, this single line grabs it for me.

```
Element Stock_Data_Change = doc.select("td.c2.l.n");
```